# What is the name for the element with two selection lists and selector buttons?

Tags: website-design, terminology

I have a design for a control looking like this:

[image]

I'd like to know if there is a commonly used name for such control to google its implementations.

Comment: Multiple selection listbox is the first thing that comes to mind

Comment: thanks, I'll check if I can google something using this name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested on Kaylee Chatham's comment, it is also called **multiple selection listbox** or **multiple choice listbox**.

As seen on number 6 in [this confusing page I found](http://designingwebinterfaces.com/15-common-components), this could also be called an **Accumulator**:

> **Description:** When a user needs to select items from separate sets of
>   search results or other large, unwieldy data sets- let them manipulate
>   the left (search, sort, navigate or filter), and add to the right.

Comment: This really depends on audience. For example, if you asked a few developers to draw a sketch of a "multiple selection listbox", you'd get variations and different interpretations. Likewise, a user probably wouldn't know what the heck you're talking about without a picture. Depending on what you're writing about, I'd be inclined not to give it a name, since it is really several controls combined into one.

Comment: I'm aware that these are two listboxes combined with other elements, but OP asks for a name to use for searching and in that case this answers the question

Answer (score 3):

I would actually consider this **more than one control**, two **list boxes** and several **buttons**.

Using the terminology recommended by the *Microsoft Manual of Style* 4th edition, you would refer to the lists as "lists" within text.

Example

> In the **Available Tasks** list, select a task, and then click the the <kbd>></kbd> button.

I would be leery to call it a "multiple selection listbox" because there are list boxes that allow users to select multiple items that are distinct from the controls shown in this question. If I needed a single word for this control, I'd probably call it "a double-paned list box", or something like that. But my preference would be to not call it anything and refer instead to individual parts. I think trying to force a name on this control as a whole would come off as jargony and not easily understood by a general user.

Comment: I completely agree with you, although OP did say they wanted a term so they could research their use rather than actually using the term.